# How do I get images to display in iOS simulator?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic framework on top of cordova. The image display when I view the app through the browser but the iOS simulator just shows a broken image link.

The image src is coming through the `ng-src` directive:

```
<img width="100%" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
```

I am creating the web server with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

I am running the iOS simulator with `cordova emulate ios` and `cordova build ios && cordova emulate ios` every once in a while which seems to do something sometimes.

Comment: what does your image path look like?

Comment: `/img/maps/street - Second Level Support Areas.jpg`

Comment: try removing the first / `img/maps/street`

Comment: yeah, of course that was all it was. I was starting the server from the www directory. Mind adding that as an answer even though it was so simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the first / `img/maps/street`